# how to print the count number in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

a query :

```
$query=mysql_query(SELECT content_id, COUNT(*) FROM votingapi_vote WHERE value_type = option  AND value = 1 GROUP BY content_id)
```

if i assign it to `$result` .

```
while ($obj = db_fetch_object ($result)) {
  $output .= $obj->content_id.'<br>' . $obj->count;
}
```

how to output the count number? after the `$obj->content_id`. there is no number printed. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an **alias** for your column `COUNT(*)` (i.e. rename the column) :

```
SELECT content_id, COUNT(*) as count FROM [...]
```

Then use the variable :

```
$obj->count
```

Answer (score 3):

Give the count an alias, like:

```
SELECT content_id, COUNT(*) as the_count FROM ...
```

Then you can refer to it by that name:

```
$output .= $obj->content_id.'<br>' . $obj->the_count;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$query=mysql_query(SELECT content_id, COUNT(*) as count FROM votingapi_vote WHERE value_type = option  AND value = 1 GROUP BY content_id)
```

Comment: +1, but I'd use a name that can't be mistaken for the `COUNT()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
COUNT(*) FROM
```

to

```
COUNT(*) as count FROM
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:   $query=mysql_query(SELECT content_id, COUNT(*) ***as the_count*** FROM votingapi_vote WHERE value_type = option  AND value = 1 GROUP BY content_id)

And then count should be in $obj->the_count